# Interpolation in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am trying to perform a linear interpolation in Python such that the interpolated values are calculated off certain values in a certain column.

In my example below, I want to interpolate Measurements for Products "a", and "b" using the actual numerical values from the relevant cells in Height column in the interpolation. Could I call the Height column the index for the interpolation?

When I am interpolating the missing Measurements for Product "a", the index values to use in interpolation are 4, 5 and 7. For interpolation of Product "b", index values to use are 1, 2.2 and 3.

I know about dataframe.interpolate() but I am struggling to modify my code to use the correct index values.

Here is the code for the dataframe I am starting with:

```
import pandas as pd
testdata1 = [('Product', ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','b']),
     ('Height', ['4', '5', '7', '1',  '2.2', '3','4']),
     ('Measurement', ['35.00', '', '55.00','10.00','','30.00','40.00']),
     ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(testdata1)
df
```

[image: testdata1]

And here is the code for the dataframe I need:

```
targetdf = [('Product', ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','b']),
     ('Height', ['4', '5', '7', '1',  '2.2', '3','4']),
     ('Measurement', ['35.00', '41.67', '55.00','10.00','22.00','30.00','40.00']),
     ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(targetdf)
df2
```

[image]

If this cannot be done with a dataframe, I am open to other ideas to do it in Python.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first some data cleaning:

```
#convert '' to `NaN`s and all strings to numeric
df['Measurement'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Measurement'], errors='coerce')
#convert strings to numeric
df['Height'] =  df['Height'].astype(float)
```

Then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) custom function with [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and get original order of columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Height') \
        .groupby('Product') \
        .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='index')) \
        .reset_index() \
        .reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
  Product  Height  Measurement
0       a     4.0    35.000000
1       a     5.0    41.666667
2       a     7.0    55.000000
3       b     1.0    10.000000
4       b     2.2    22.000000
5       b     3.0    30.000000
6       b     4.0    40.000000
```

Comment: Please could you explain the reset index, and reindex parts of your code? It's not 100% clear to me. Thanks

Comment: sure - `reset-index` only create column from index and `reindex` change order of columns names. the best is try remove this part of code for see difference.